# Save layer file with different Definition Query with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, python, layer-file

I would like to save a new layer file with different definition query, but receive `TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable.`

```
import arcpy

lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer("\path to  layer file\ layerFile.lyr")
field = 'Date_1'
values = "'1950'"
query=str(field) + "=" + str(values)
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(lyrFile, "Name of Layer"):
    lyr.definitionQuery(query)
    lyr.saveACopy("new layerfile.lyr")
```

Error I receive is:

```
lyr.definitionQuery(query)
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

How can I adjust the code so could save layer files with different definition queries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`definitionQuery` is not a method. It is a property of the `Layer` class. Since it returns a string, you encounter that error.

It can be used like this:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = query
```

Comment: Thank you, Kubra. The code worked without errors. But still doesn't apply definition query. Basically it saves original layer file.